ONDC search by location
I am trying to implement search by location in ONDC. and constructing payload as below:
{
    "context": {
      "domain": "ONDC:RET10",
      "country": "IND",
      "city": "std:080",
      "action": "search",
      "core_version": "1.1.0",
      "bap_id": "****************",
      "bap_uri": "********************",
      "transaction_id": "c0c2f570-df00-4f58-ae62-fe737fe8e5be",
      "message_id": "7f6f1fad-df2e-4a78-9c5e-b0322e6a87ab",
      "timestamp": "2024-11-11T18:09:52.493Z",
      "ttl": "PT30S"
    },
    "message": {
      "intent": {
        "item": {
          "descriptor": {
            "name": "snapbizz"
          }
        },
        "fulfillment": {
          "type": "Delivery",
          "end": {
            "location": {
              "gps": "12.9812430000001,77.5950340000001"
            }
          }
        },
        "payment": {
          "@ondc/org/buyer_app_finder_fee_type": "percent",
          "@ondc/org/buyer_app_finder_fee_amount": "3.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }

I am unable to get expected results for different scenarios.

Help us help you - explain what exactly is the problem
